# Why does an op amp need to be powered before applying the input signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I was taught that a power supply needs to be applied to an op amp before an input signal. I understand that doing that in the wrong order fries the chip, but why?

Comment: Hmm, I've applied signals to opamps plenty of times without any measurable degradation.  "I've got no signal, what's wrong"... scratch scratch.  check here, check there... "Oh, I forgot to plug in the power supply!".. head slap.  Today's input protection circuitry seems pretty good.  limiting the current helps.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all ICs are designed with the assumption that the input and (usually) output voltages will remain between the power supply inputs at all times.  To ensure this, most ICs have protection diodes between the input pins and the power suppy and ground terminals.

If you apply power to an input when the IC not powered, these protection diodes will conduct, and attempt to power the IC - and any othter ICs connected to the supply rails.  This will cause current to flow along paths that the designer didn't intend, and may cause damage to the IC.

Comment: one way to fix this is to put series resistors on the inputs to the opamp, such as 10k resistors. This helps reduce current flow in strange conditions, and i've often seen it suggested in opamp datasheets for making them "fool proof"

Answer (score 3):

The op amp's positive supply is designed to be biased to the most positive voltage and its negative supply is designed to be biased to the most negative voltage. If an input signal is applied while the supplies are not powered the input voltage may be higher than the positive supply or lower than the negative supply. If that happens a \$pn\$ junction (e.g. a diode or in a transistor) inside the op amp can become biased in a way not expected by the op amp designers.

To illustrate, here is the I-V curve for a diode:

[image]

The current through the diode is an exponential function of the forward voltage, and it is also very high if a reverse bias voltage greater than the reverse breakdown voltage is applied. A very high current through the \$pn\$ junction can damage the junction (which would "fry" the op amp). If the input voltage is too high above the positive supply or too far below the negative supply then such a high current may be generated.

The input of an op amp typically looks similar to this:

[image]

The diodes marked ESD are inside the op amp and attempt to limit the voltage on the input pins \$V_{P}\$ and \$V_{N}\$ here) so that an electrostatic discharge does not cause the inputs to rise too far above the positive supply (\$V_{CC}\$) or too far below the negative supply (\$V_{EE}\$). If either input pin's voltage rises above \$V_{CC}\$ then the ESD diode between that input pin and \$V_{CC}\$ will be forward biased and conduct current to limit the voltage across the diode. Similarly, if either input pin's voltage falls below \$V_{EE}\$ then the ESD diode between that input pin and \$V_{EE}\$ will be forward biased. As long as the current conducted by these diodes is small then the diode will be in the flat part of the diode I-V curve in the forward region. But if the voltage across the ESD diode is too high (e.g. because it is *driven* by a voltage source at the input) then a large current will be conducted, destroying the diodes and "frying" the op amp.

More information, including the op amp input circuit, can be found [here](http://edn.com/design/analog/4399004/Key-benefits-of-input-over-voltage-protected-op-amps-in-systems).

Comment: There are other PN junctions besides the ones that are intended to be diodes -- a bipolar chip with NPN and PNP transistors includes these "parasitic" NPNP or PNPN SCRs, which can go into damaging latchup if not properly biased by a power supply. If you go beyond the rails then certain PN junctions become forward biased, turning on these SCRs and allowing large currents to flow through structures other than the intended transistors. If too much current flows in the wrong areas, the device can be permanently damaged.

Comment: @MarkU Yes, this is a good example. I did not include the example of latch-up since the IC should be tested for susceptibility for latch-up prior to release and a customer should (ideally) never see such a condition.